# matching logs with schedule on flexi-time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a module where the system would be able to determine where the logs of a flexi-time schedule belong...

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a table called office_schedule with fields and values:

```
emp_ID            time_in                time_out
  1               8:00:00                9:00:00
  1               9:30:00                12:00:00
  1              13:30:00                17:00:00
```

The example table Above 'office_schedule' Contains the values of schedule of a single employee in a single day. Given that I have another table called 'office_logs' with a value:

```
emp_ID           log_in           log_out
  1              8:40:00          11:30:00
```

I searching for a query that would take the employee's logs and try to determine which value in 'office_schedule' table the logs belong to, by calculating the most value of time it has covered.

for example, if I query using the logs in 'office logs' table, it would match the second value of 'office_schedule' table, because the logs cover more span of time in the 'office_schedule' table's second value than the others.

i hope this is understandable enough.
please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the time cells are defined as TIME and not as VARCHAR, I would try something like that (but maybe there is a better way):

```
SELECT * FROM `office_logs` as log LEFT JOIN `office_schedule` AS sched ON log.`emp_ID` = sched.`emp_ID` WHERE log.`emp_ID` = 1 ORDER BY (ABS(sched.`Time_in` - log.`log_in`) + ABS(sched.`Time_out` - log.`log_out`)) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

It calculates the absolute difference between the log in and log out times of an employee to each of his scheduled time in and time out. The return is ordered by the smallest difference.

Maybe this helps.